# Make ID field invisible in detailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how can I easily customize my detailsView that when it is in Create mode ID field should be invisible

I can rememebr that it was sth like visible = <% code here ... (IsCreated ??)

here is an example:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="myDS"
    Width="50%" DataKeyNames="MyId">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="MyId">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="xxx" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("MyId") visible=" **(if create mode than invisible else visible)** %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

thanks for help

Comment: Can you give more detail, there is not enough to go off in your question.

Comment: done, must type anything to reach 15 chars ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Visible="<%# this.IsCreated %>"
```